# When is it better to use an NSSet over an NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I have used NSSets many times in my apps, but I have never created one myself.

When is it better to use an [`NSSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/) as opposed to an [`NSArray`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSArray) and why?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

When the order of the items in the collection is not important, sets offer better performance for finding items in the collection.

The reason is that a set uses hash values to find items (like a dictionary) while an array has to iterate over its entire contents to find a particular object.

Comment: @rohan-patel Correct is O(1) vs O(n)

Comment: If ordered: O(1) vs O(logn) since binary search is applicable. If unordered, then O(1) vs O(n)

Answer (score 183):

The image from [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Collections.html) describes it very well:

[image: Objective-C Collections]

`Array` is an **ordered** (order is maintained when you add) sequence of elements

```
[array addObject:@1];
[array addObject:@2];
[array addObject:@3];
[array addObject:@4];
[array addObject:@6];
[array addObject:@4];
[array addObject:@1];
[array addObject:@2];

[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 4, 1, 2]
```

`Set` is a **distinct** (no duplicates), **unordered** list of elements

```
[set addObject:@1];
[set addObject:@2];
[set addObject:@3];
[set addObject:@4];
[set addObject:@6];
[set addObject:@4];
[set addObject:@1];
[set addObject:@2];

[1, 2, 6, 4, 3]
```

Comment: In your example, you are adding primitives to an array and a set. Neither is possible because they can only contain objects.

Comment: Thanks for your edit @Zaheer, but it was actually invalid. I wasn't adding primitives. I was adding literals.

Comment: For ordered collection of data and no duplicates you can use NSOrderedSet which is already introduces in iOS 5 and later.

Answer (score 67):

The best answer is to this is [Apple's own documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Collections.html).

[image]

The main difference is that `NSArray` is for an ordered collection and `NSSet` is for an unordered collection.

There are several articles out there that talk about the difference in speed between the two, like [this one](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/08/nsarray-or-nsset-nsdictionary-or.html). If you're iterating through an unordered collection, `NSSet` is great. However, in many cases, you need to do things that only an `NSArray` can do, so you sacrifice the speed for those abilities.

**NSSet**

- Primarily access items by comparison
- Unordered
- Does not allow duplicates

**NSArray**

- Can access items by index
- Ordered
- Allows duplicates

That's all there really is to it! Let me know if that helps.

Comment: You don't have to always sacrifice `NSSet` for the sake of indexing. It's common to use two different data structures for the same data. Or you build and index on that array :) But then it's better to use a DB which has it alredy implemented.

Comment: "Build an index on that array". You cannot make an index on a NSSet. There are many different techniques you can use. And if you need to make sacrifices in BOTH memory and processing power, then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Since the question is about `NSSet` and `NSArray`, my answer is accurate and complete. Yes, you can build other data structures, but I'm just comparing these two.

Comment: I did upvote but your answer is incorrect when you speak about sacrifices. If you need some functionality from `NSArray` and some functioanlity from `NSSet`, the correct answer is not "use `NSArray` and sacrifice performance". The answer is combine both or use a different data structure.

Comment: I would have said the main difference is set is for unique objects where as an array can have duplicates. The order aspect is secondary to that fact.

Comment: "If you're iterating through an unordered collection, NSSet is great." - this is inaccurate. According to the article that you linked, NSArray is more efficient when it comes to the iterations, whether it's ordered or not: "Lesson: if you only need to iterate contents, don't use an NSSet." When you have to do a lot of lookups - then NSSet should be the data structure of choice.

Answer (score 12):

NSOrderedSet is available in iOS 5+ so with that the main difference becomes whether you want duplicate objects in the data structure.

Answer (score 9):

**NSArray**:

1. Ordered collection of data
2. Allows duplicates
3. It is collection type object

**NSSet**:

1. Unordered collection of data
2. Does not allow duplicates
3. It is also collection type object

Answer (score 7):

An array is used to access items by their index. Any item can be inserted into the array multiple times. Arrays mantain the order of their elements.

A set is used basically only to check if the item is in the collection or not. The items have no concept of order or indexing. You cannot have an item in a set twice.

If an array wants to check if it contains an element, it has to check all its items. Sets are designed to use faster algorithms.

You can imagine a set like a dictionary without values.

Note that array and set are not the only data structures. There are other, e.g. Queue, Stack, Heap, Fibonacci's Heap. I would recommend reading a book about algorithms and data structures.

See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28computer_science%29) for more information.

Comment: Actually, an array only needs to be checked up to the point that the item is found. If the item IS in the array, very rarely will every item need to be checked.

Comment: Yes, as you say "if the item IS in the array". If you expect this, you don't have to check if it's there or not. The complexity of the `contains` operation is `O(n)`. Number of comparisons when not in the array is `n`. The average number of comparisons when the object is in the array is `n/2`. Even if the object is found, the performance is awful.

Comment: Performance would only be awful with a large array. If you knew the array could become quite large, then there are ways you could improve performance of the array, such as using an array of arrays.

Comment: If the equality operation is expensive, you will see the difference even on arrays with 3 items. And the same behaviour as a large array can happen whan you repeat the operation a lot (e.g. use the operation in a 'for' cycle). Have you heard about amortized complexity? The complexity is still linear and the performance is awful compared to a set (usually with constant complexity).

Comment: Obviously there will be a difference, I'm just stating that the big o notation is exponential; with small arrays, the difference will be minuscule. Also, `NSArray`s have other speed advantages over `NSSet`s. As always, it's a tradeoff.

Answer (score 5):

```
NSArray *Arr;
NSSet *Nset;

Arr=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"2",@"1", nil];
Nset=[NSSet setWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"3",@"5",@"5", nil];

NSLog(@"%@",Arr);
NSLog(@"%@",Nset);
```

the array

> 2015-12-04 11:05:40.935 [598:15730] ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1 )

the set

> 2015-12-04 11:05:43.362 [598:15730] { ( 3, 1, 2, 5 )}

Answer (score 4):

The main differences have already been given in other answers.

I'd just like to note that because of the way sets and dictionaries are implemented (i.e. using hashes),one should be careful not to use mutable objects for the keys.

If a key is mutated then the hash will (probably) change too, pointing to a different index/bucket in the hash table. The original value won't be deleted and will actually be taken into account when enumerating or asking the structure for its size/count.

This can lead to some really hard to locate bugs.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/08/nsarray-or-nsset-nsdictionary-or.html) you can find a pretty thorough comparison of the `NSArray` and `NSSet` datastructures.

Short conclusions:

> Yes, NSArray is faster than NSSet for simply holding and iterating. As little as 50% faster for constructing and as much as 500% faster for iterating. Lesson: if you only need to iterate contents, don't use an NSSet.
>
> Of course, if you need to test for inclusion, work hard to avoid NSArray. Even if you need both iteration and inclusion testing, you should probably still choose an NSSet. If you need to keep your collection ordered and also test for inclusion, then you should consider keeping two collections (an NSArray and an NSSet), each containing the same objects.
>
> NSDictionary is slower to construct than NSMapTable — since it needs to copy the key data. It makes up for this by being faster to lookup. Of course, the two have different capabilities so most of the time, this determination should be made on other factors.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

You would typically use a **Set when access speed is of the essence and order doesn’t matter**, or is determined by other means (through a predicate or sort descriptor). Core Data for example uses sets when managed objects are accessed via a to-many relationship

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a bit of it i use set sometimes just to remove duplicates from array like :-

```
NSMutableSet *set=[[NSMutableSet alloc]initWithArray:duplicateValueArray]; // will remove all the duplicate values
```